# How to pass value to a Controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want following URL using code Igniter:

http:///www.mywebsite.com/Mumbai/Types/Car

How to get above URL?

Steps: 1) View the website and Select the City like Mumbai , Kolkata, Ahmedabad 2) URL will be example.com/Mumbai 
3) Display Types like (Car, Bike,etc) 4) Display URL as example.com/Mumbai/type/Car

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->uri->segment()` for this.

Example: by using `$this->uri->segment(1)` will give you "Mumbai" and `$this->uri->segment(3)` will give you "car" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In general the CI url structure is `www.sample.com/controller/function/yourparmeters`  So you can generate 
 like this

```
http:///www.mywebsite.com/SampleController/GetFunction/Mumbai/Types/Car
```

Or if you want same url

```
http:///www.mywebsite.com/Mumbai/Types/Car
```

You should use set route first

```
$route['ci/home'] = "ci/site_controller/GetFunction";



class SampleController extends CI_Controller 
{



    public function GetFunction($city,$type,$car)
    {
        //Your stuff here

        $this->load->view("myview");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Vijay,
When I load the page City name wil going to display so my URL will be www.example.com (with default index method in my CITY controller).

Once I will click on City name say Mumbai, My URL will be www.example.com/Mumbai/Type and the page display the Types like Car, Bike etc

after clicking Bike, I want a URL like www.example.com/Mumbai/Types/Car

Hope you got my point now.